# SSRS Expression help multiple Conditions

Tags: c#, sql-server, reporting-services

```
=IIF((Fields!len.Value<=27) AND (Fields!oLastRegRetail.Value>0) then Fields!Retail.Value/Fields!oLastRegRetail.Value) second if
=IIF(Fields!len.Value>27) AND (Fields!Regular.Value>0) then Fields!Retail.Value/Fields!Regular.Value if both false-"N/A"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems your `IIF` condition is broken. Here's the fixed version.

```
=IIF(Fields!len.Value <= 27 AND Fields!len.Value > 27 AND Fields!Regular.Value > 0
    ,Fields!Retail.Value/Fields!oLastRegRetail.Value
    ,"N/A")
```

or if your trying to do nested `IIF`

```
=IIF(Fields!len.Value <= 27  and Fields!Regular.Value > 0
    ,Fields!Retail.Value/Fields!oLastRegRetail.Value
    ,IIF(Fields!len.Value > 27 and Fields!Regular.Value > 0
        ,Fields!Retail.Value/Fields!Regular.Value, "N/A")
)
```

Comment: if Fields!len.Value<=27 AND Fields!oLastRegRetail.Value>0 then Fields!Retail.Value/Fields!oLastRegRetail.Value next IF Fields!len.Value>27 AND Fields!Regular.Value>0 then Fields!Retail.Value/Fields!Regular.Value,else both "N/A") i want to combine them both

Comment: @YaseenMohammed, check my 2nd IIF